# Не могу установить django (Unable to create process using '"')

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pip

Windows 10. Пытался через pip и easy_install, но получал один и тот же неудовлетворительный результат:

```
  PS C:\Python364\Scripts> pip install django<2
Collecting django<2
  Using cached Django-1.11.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from django<2)
  Using cached pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pytz, django
Successfully installed django-1.11.9 pytz-2017.3
PS C:\Python364\Scripts> django-admin --version
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:
Пропишите путь до интерпретатора python в переменную PATH и выполните: python -m pip install XXX

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не помогло, увы

Comment: И какие ошибки выдает? Что пишет?